# How to pass a Laravel filtered collection as array to Vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a component which I'm trying to make it receive an array.

If I do it like this in a blade file:

```
<mega-menu :grouped-categories="{{ $categories->toJson() }}"></mega-menu>
```

**It works as intended. It appears in Vue as array.**

However, if I try to run some collection methods like **'filter'** and **'groupBy'** and then apply 'toJson', Vue receives it as an Object which is not what I need.

```
<mega-menu
  :grouped-categories="{{ $categories->filter(function($category) { return $category['enabled']; })->groupBy('group)->toJson() }}">
</mega-menu>
```

I'm suspicious that something is happening during filtering or grouping that converts it into an array. Any ideas on how to manipulate ´$categories´ variable which is an instance of Collection and make it pass as array to Vue?

Comment: Well, in PHP associative and regular arrays are hard to distinguish. Mapped to JS, associative arrays become objects, regular arrays become arrays.

Comment: Probably your returning not a proper result, don't call the filter or groupBy in your blade do it in your controller and pass the variable as json format.

Comment: @Vivick So basically I need to rebuild the associative array in the Vue component?

Comment: You'll get an Object, which you will have to manipulate (might use `Object.entries`)

Comment: @JesusErwinSuarez I'm returning the proper result. The problem is as Vivick states, an associative array pass as object to JS.

Comment: Thanks Vivick. One thing learned today :)

Comment: @Richard-MX have you try `<mega-menu :grouped-categories=@json($categories)></mega-menu>`

Comment: Thanks @RutvijKothari, tried that, didn't work as "I expected". Vivick tip is the good one :)

Comment: @Richard-MX great that you have the idea of Vivic

Comment: well why dont try to store that query on to a variable first then return it, then on the page  :grouped-categories={{json_encode($thenewVar)}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the information provided by **@Vivick**, the associative arrays pass to Javascript as Objects. So I'll handle the Object inside the Vue component.

Comment: This is not 100% accurate. For instance, if you're using vuetify's <v-select> items should be an array (it can be an array of objects, but an array). So, in this sort of situations passing the object as is doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

To avoid problems with special chars add [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/de/function.addslashes.php) in template like:

```
:users="'{{ addslashes(\App\Users::all()->toJson()) }}'"
```

In vue component get the Users as prop:

```
props: {
    users: String
},
```

And add it to data

```
data() {
    return {
        users: JSON.parse(this.mailinglists)
    };
},
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
v-bind:color="{{json_encode($yourVariable)}}"
```

in element

for example:

```
<color-item v-bind:color="{{json_encode($yourVariable)}}" ></color-item>
```

in your controller:

```
$myArray = array("name" => "لوازمات");
$item =  "لوازمات";
$collection = Color::all();


return view('home', compact('item', 'collection', 'myArray', ...));
```

in your blade:

```
@extends('layouts.app', ['item' => $item,'myArray' => $myArray, 'colors'=> $collection])
```

pass variable into vuejs:

```
<primary-header 
   :colors="{{json_encode($colors)}}" 
   :item="{{json_encode($item)}}" 
   v-bind:my-array="{{json_encode($myArray)}}">
```

in your vuejs file

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{item}}
        {{colors[0].name}}
        {{myArray.name}}
  
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        name: "primary-header",
        props: {
            item:  String,
            myArray: Object,
            colors: Array
        },
        methods: {
        }
    };
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```